# Instantiate GameObjects and change Material when it hits on the ground

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a code for instantiate cube into the list and change a  Material of each clone when it hits on the ground

The following code works but not in *Real-Time*. *Update* function works like a *Start* function for a *Foreach* method

How to get a value of  ***item.transform.position.y*** in the Update function Real-Time?

```
public GameObject cubePrefab;
public Material RedMat;
public float GroudLevel = 0.5f;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    { 
         List<GameObject> cloneList = new List<GameObject>();
         //instantiate clones into the list
         for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
         {
            var clone = Instantiate (cubePrefab,new Vector3(Random.Range(-3f, 3f),
            Random.Range(4f, 10.5f),Random.Range(-3f, 3f)), Quaternion.identity);
            cloneList.Add(clone);
         }

         //if clone is grounded change a Material for each clone
         foreach (var item in cloneList)
         {
            //Debug.Log(item.transform.position.y);

            //check if clone is on the ground
            if(item.transform.position.y < GroudLevel)
            {
             item.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = RedMat;
            }
            
        }  

    }
}
```

There is a screenshot for a *GroudLevel* = 7

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason this function isn't working is because the pivot (`transform.position`) of your item is always ***in the center of the object***. This isn't something you can change in Unity (nor would you necessarily *want* to).

On top of this, you're checking if the item is **under** the ground, **and not on it** when you use `<` insteaad of `<=`, because the position needs to be less than `groundLevel` to return true.

There are several solutions here.

The simplest would involve moving all of this logic to an `OnCollisionEnter` or `OnTriggerEnter` method. For more information on this, check the [Unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html).

Another solution would be to find a way tthe size of the object, divide it by two, and check if

```
item.transform.position - halfSize <= groundLevel;
```

***This seems really cumbersome and overly complex, however***. You'd be better off using Unity's built-in collision system, unless you have a reason not to.